# Why does not it work method Thread?

Tags: android

Good afternoon. I am new to programming. That's decided to learn some json. Wrote the code . Which takes json and displays the text . But in the course of work , faced with this

Why does not it work method Thread?
I just want to display the code json

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread thread=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://irkvuz.ru/isea/timetable/get/get_schedule.php?group_id=14925");
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String line = "";
                    String str = "";
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        str+=line;
                    }
                    jsonArray=new JSONArray(str);
                } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        try {
          //EXEPTION THIS IS 
    Log.e("asdasda",jsonArray.get(0).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
```

Comment: you can touch the ui from a thread that is not the ui/main thread. `textView.setText`, in this case, is making your application crash `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`

Comment: Simple example here try this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @Blackbelt, Crush not. the program is stable

Comment: then it is not even reaching that line. Did you add the internet permission to the manifest?

Comment: We can spend the day long trying to figure out **what** is not working, meanwhile you'll probably be getting more and more negative votes. Instead, you could try to improve your question saying what is it what's not working and what evidences you have.

Comment: @nKn, Okay. Then I change the code. I update. Why not create jsonArray?. I have not created it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread thread=new Thread(){
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://irkvuz.ru/isea/timetable/get/get_schedule.php?group_id=14925");
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String line = "";
                    String str = "";
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        str+=line;
                    } 
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    textView.setText(jsonArray.toString());
                    }
                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            } 
        }; 

        thread.start();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work

Comment: Does not work,,, Reason?

Comment: check the updated answer, use json object instead of json array..